# Error java.lang.NumberFormatException : For input string:

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql, el

I have started using Spring MVC and hibernate few days back and I am facing one error.

My Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TESTERS")
public class Questioner {

    @Id

    @Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;



    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }


    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }




}
```

My DAOImpl Query

```
public List<Questioner> listTester() { 
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("" +
                    "SELECT t.firstname,t.lastname FROM Questioner t,Program p " +
                    "where t.programid=p.programid ").list(); 
}
```

My Controller for getting this data and passing to jsp file

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tester")
public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map)
{
map.put("testerTableGet", testerservice.listTester());
return "tester";
}
```

My JSP File where I am displaying this data

```
<c:forEach items="${testerTableGet}" var="tester">
<tr>
<td>${tester.lastname}, ${tester.firstname}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

The query is working fine and it also getting the data needed from database , also my Questioner and Program Class has correct mapping from the database include datatype.

But while executing I am getting below error.

```
Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "lastname"
java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:166)
javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:46)
org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:1026)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tester_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f4(tester_jsp.java:387)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.tester_jsp._jspService(tester_jsp.java:223)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Can anybody help ?

Thanks.

Comment: There should not be comma before FROM in SELECT t.firstname,t.lastname,FROM Questioner

Comment: Oh Sorry it's typo mistake while posting in real its working. I have edit it

Comment: Post the full stack trace, so that we know where this exception comes from. Also, it seems you missed the part about associations between entities in the manual. This is an extremely important part. You shouldn't have IDs to other entities in your entities, but associations between them.

Comment: Please also specify what is class you return from DAO

Comment: @WandMaker Hey I have include class where I am return DAO Please see the original post

Comment: @JBNizet Hey I have include full stack trace in the original post. But i don't get "part about associations between entities in the manual" in your question can please be more specific about this ?

Comment: OneToMany, ManyToOne, OneToOne, ManyToMany associations are an essential part of JPA. Read http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association. There should be a ManyToOne association from Questioner to Program.

Answer (score 3):

The query above returns a `List<Object[]>`. So, in your JSP, inside `forEach`, the tester variable references an `Object[]`. And `Object[]` dorsn't have any lastname (or firstname) property.

You're missing a loop which transforms a loop that transforms the `List<Object[]>` into a `List<User>` before placing the list into the model.

Or you should change the query to

```
SELECT t FROM Questioner t,Program p ...
```

which would return a `List<Questioner>` instead of a `List<Object[]>`.

Comment: Ok. Can  you let know how to transforms the List<Object[]> into a List<User> ? Or what if I have use List<Object[]> in my JSP page. because my query will have result something like t.firstname,t.lastname,p.programid So it will not have only List<User> .

Comment: You will have to define relation between Questioner and Program in your Entity, I guess by making a member attribute in Questioner of type Program.  Also, use JPA Query and not SQL query.

Comment: Create a class containing the fields that your query retrieves, the loop over the List<Object[]>, and at each iteration, create an instance of this class.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry then.  My mistake.  Generally, the FROM clause will have only entity listed in JPA QL so that the return values are of that type.

Comment: @JBNizet hey I found another way where I created one view with all the  data that I want and then create class for that view and fetch it. What do you is this efficient way of doing ? and by the way it's working.

Comment: I wouldn't do that. First of all, it forces you to change the database schema each time your query changes. And second, if you update one of the entities taking part of the view and you already have the "view" entity loaded, it won't be refreshed.